# Google App Engine - cannot resolve method 'execute()', but project compiles

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm writing an Android client that works with a Google App Engine backend. The client compiles and runs just fine, but the `execute()` method is yet unidentified.

My AsyncTask's `doInBackground(...)`:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    context = params[0].first;
    if(mService == null) {
        DatastoreRequests.Builder builder = new DatastoreRequests.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl(myRootUrl);
        mService = builder.build();
    }

    try {
        return String.valueOf(mService.sayHi(params[0].second).execute()); // 'execute' is red colored
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

sayHi:

```
public DatastoreRequests.SayHi sayHi(String name) throws IOException {
    DatastoreRequests.SayHi result = new DatastoreRequests.SayHi(name);
    this.initialize(result);
    return result;
}
```

As I mentioned, the code does run, and for example, when removing the `String.valueOf()` method - the build fails. So, why is it unrecognized? Any explanation for such behavior and how to solve it? Thanks.

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1.

Comment: please show signature of `mService.sayHi`

Comment: I'm not sure what the term 'signature' means in this context (I wasn't in charge of creating the backend, if that matters). If you were referring to the function in mService, I added it to the main question (note that it appears the same with other functions as well).

Comment: right, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature 
Now please show `DatastoreRequests.SayHi` method `execute`. 
Also, maybe I misunderstand, do you get error on this line when executing, or just IDEA syntax highlighter shows an error? if you have build or execution error, please add stacktrace

Comment: It's just the IDE. I can dismiss it, but I'm afraid I've done something wrong which may affect my work later.

Comment: oh, I see. was confused by `build fails`. i guess it's something with IDEA dependencies, or other config. anyway, if it compiles and works, then it's fine

Comment: The method signature is actually `DatastoreRequests.SayHi` (sorry for not understand at first).